# Is there a tool similar to repo or git-repo for hg/Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I am a bit new to hg and while I am familiar with the python-based `repo` tool (used in project like the Android Open Source Project) I am not aware of one for Mercurial.  Is there such a tool for hg?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with `repo`, but my understanding was that it allowed them to construct a project out of lots of smaller repositories.

If that's the case then it's just built in. [Subrepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository).

Comment: Is subrepo stable?  I have heard the feature is not too mature.

Comment: They've been around since 1.3 (July 2009), and were made core in 1.4.x sometime I think. We're now on 2.0. Pretty stable these days as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Edlund was kind enough to open-source their [repoman](https://bitbucket.org/hstuart/repoman) tool, which was directly inspired by the Android project's repo tool as I understand the history.