# how to mirror hg repo to git repo?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, dvcs

this issue is a bit similar to [Is there a tool similar to repo or git-repo for hg/Mercurial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138710/is-there-a-tool-similar-to-repo-or-git-repo-for-hg-mercurial), the difference is my focus is how to mirror that hg repo to git repo?

is there a command like git hg clone?

i want to use git to manage my code, but some open source code is just hosted on hg, so how to mirror them to git repo?

btw, can i push hg repo to more than one hg repos?

Comment: "can i push hg repo to more than one hg repos?" is a completely different question. Please post it as a separate question (or start by reading the `push` docs, though I suspect you may mean "at the same time").

Answer (score 0):

Mirror git and mercurial repos [the lazy way](http://geekswithblogs.net/gregorymalcolm/archive/2012/03/17/mirroring-mercurial-and-git-changes-the-lazy-way.aspx) and [here](http://hg-git.github.com/)

Comment: "lazy way" isn't bullet-proof, because at least HG (can) have some meta-data in files inside WC-dir (.hgignore, .hgsub*)

Answer (score 0):

1 [Mirror from hg to git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12557927/960558) (and back) with hg-git

2 Yes, you can have any amount of remote repos of any (supported) type in [path] section for local repo and push to all and any of these repos by the a set of consecutive push or combining pushes into new command with the help of alias(es)